# how to reuse components and pass props in vue 3 and vitejs and laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, laravel-9

im using laravel 9, vitjs and vue3 to create an app.
im new in vue3 and vitjs and i started to create vue components and use them

my codes to register component in `app.js`:

```
import { createApp } from "vue"
import testcomponent from './components/testcomponent.vue';

createApp(testcomponent).mount('#app');
```

ok, I have `<div id="app"></div>` in my laravel blade file which my component load in it and displays fine.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>

@vite(['resources/sass/app.scss'])

</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>

@vite(['resources/js/app.js'])
</body>
```

But what should I do if I want to pass props to my component?
why we cant use component like as vue2 (tags) like this: `<testcomponent></testcomponent>`
Is this way because of vue3 or vitejs?

Comment: you can pass props by same way as it is used in `vue2`. Can plz add your code snippet that you have tried?

Comment: @khawarAli I put all the codes in the question
Now I have included the view (blade) codes in my question
I don't have any component in the view that I can pass the props to!!!

Comment: what error are you getting? what is not working?

Comment: i have not error bro!!! cant you understand my question?
in this way i have no any component in my blade (its only a div tag with id="app")
so my question is how can i pass props from my blade to the component? ok? there is no any component tag in my blade

Answer (score 2):

###### STEP 1: Register Vue app by following way

```
import { createApp, defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";
const app = createApp({});

//register component globally
const testcomponent= defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./components/testcomponent.vue'));
app.component('test-component', testcomponent);

app.mount('#app');
```

###### different ways to import component:

1st Way:

```
import testcomponent from './components/testcomponent.vue';
```

2nd Way:

```
const testcomponent = import("./components/testcomponent.vue")
```

3rd Way:

```
const testcomponent = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./components/testcomponent.vue'))
```

###### STEP 2: call a component using `tags` in `blade`.

```
<div id="app">
<test-component :prop-name="{{ json_encode($Obj) }}"></test-component>
</div>
```

Plz try it.

Comment: thank you. I did this method now, but the blank page is displayed and the component is not loaded

Comment: no any ideas bro?

Comment: Can you plz tell me what error you have in console tab?

Comment: i have not error

Comment: I think you will need to change import component statement in `app.js`. Try some other import mechnism

Comment: What method do you suggest?

Comment: @K1-Aria I have update my answer plz check new changes and try them all. also make sure you component path is right

Comment: Hello and apologies for my late reply, unfortunately it still does not work and does not display the component.

Comment: Hi @K1-Aria sorry for late reply. I'm sharing you an my public github repository link plz use it's code to achieve you task https://github.com/M-khawar/postalcode-component-example. and If it's works for you plz mark my answer as accepted. and if you have any other question feel free to ping me.

Comment: hi @khawar Ali. i solved the problem! it was because of Vitejs...
in vitejs and laravel we cant load components as legacy mode (using tags)